# Issue with Integer Conversion

Tags: c++, integer, type-conversion, uac

```
int left = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
int right = -1;
//the code below instead of give one more than int_max gives: 18446744071562067968
unsigned long long result = left * right;
```

I've tried to look up UAC but even according to UAC rules this should produce correct output. Any ideas why the result is incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's undefined behavior to multiply the minimum value of a signed 2's complement `int` by -1, because the result is outside the range of the type.

In this case your output is consistent with the result having been -2147483648, i.e. the overflow appears to have wrapped around. You cannot rely on wraparound for signed types, only unsigned types.

Assigning the result of a calculation to `unsigned long long` does not change what type the calculation is performed in. As soon as you do the multiplication, you lose. So, convert one of the operands to `unsigned long long` *before* multiplying.

Comment: #Steve Jessop, shouldn't that cause overflow? Just like with max_int? Is there a rule which explains this behavior?

Comment: @smallB: signed overflow is undefined behavior in C++, it is *not* guaranteed to wrap around. It often does wrap around (and that's consistent with the result you saw), but common compilers like gcc contain optimizations that can break your code if it contains overflows that you assume will wrap around, but the compiler assumes do not happen because they're forbidden. 5/4, "If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically deﬁned or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 4):

Both operands are `int`, so arithmetic is performed within the `int` type; the result of the operation overflows the range of `int`, so the result is undefined.

To get the result you expect, cast one operand to `long long` first:

```
 unsigned long long result = left * (long long) right;
```

This is still potentially undefined behaviour; it's safer to convert to unsigned arithmetic as early as possible (since unsigned arithmetic wraps and doesn't overflow):

```
unsigned long long result = left * (unsigned long long) right;
```

Note that the result you arrived at is `0xffffffff80000000`; this indicates that the actual result of the operation was `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` in the `int` type, which was then sign-extended and cast to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @smallB: what did you expect? Try the above and see if that is what you wanted. I consider Steve Jessop's answer above  as being more correct.

Answer (score 0):

Tha cause is that the multiplication is commited in terms of `int`.

Both arguments are `int`, so multiplications gives an `int` agein, and you were right, it gives `int_max` + 1 which is equivivalent to `int_min`=-2147483648. So it is actually -2147483648, but for unsigned long long it is equivivalent to 18446744071562067968, see hex codes:

```
                       int_min =         80000000 
(unsigned long long) (int min) = ffffffff80000000
```